# Get Order Line Item cost in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the COST of a line item in the WC order backend. (Seen in the attached image:[image]

Online I've read that I can do this, but all that seems to do is print out my line item total. I can't seem to find a cost function. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    $orderLineItems = $order->get_items();

    /* @var $order_item WC_Order_Item_Product */
    foreach ($orderLineItems as $item_id => $order_item) {

      var_dump($order_item->get_total());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cost by dividing the total with the quantity.

```
echo 'Cost: '.$order_item->get_subtotal() / $order_item->get_quantity();
echo '<br />';
echo 'Subtotal: '.$order_item->get_subtotal();
echo '<br />';
echo 'Total: '.$order_item->get_total();
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming - that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    You can get the cost by order item.

```
// Order Id 
  $order_id = 502;
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object (same as before)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $order_item):
   $item_name    = $order_item->get_name(); // Name of the product
    $quantity     = $order_item->get_quantity();  // quantity of the product
    $tax_class    = $order_item->get_tax_class();
    $line_subtotal     = $order_item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal (non discounted)
    $line_subtotal_tax = $order_item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax (non discounted)
    $line_total        = $order_item->get_total(); // Line total (discounted)
    $line_total_tax    = $order_item->get_total_tax(); // Line total tax (discounted)

endforeach;
```